# On the Name of the Amplituhedron

Tags: terminology, physics, polyhedra, polytopes

Shouldn't the 'amplituhedron' really be called an 'amplitutope' since it's really a polytope and not strictly a polyhedron?

Comment: Have you thought of emailing your concerns about the nomenclature of the amplituhedron to its discoverers? :) Seriously, amplituhedron sounds way better than amplitutope, just like "renormalization group" sounds better than "renormalization semigroup".

Comment: No; actually, I haven't.  (What is or are the creator's, discoverer's, creators', or discoverers' e-mail address or addresses?)  When it comes to naming conventions, though, I would rather have objects' and concepts' names reflect their composition; in this light, 'renormalization group' would be okay to use as short-hand for 'renormalization semi-group' since a semi-group is also a group, but 'amplituhedron' would not be acceptable as a suitable name for what should really be called an 'amplitutope' since all polyhedrons are polytopes but not all polytopes are polyhedrons.

Comment: Presumably it was named in the tradition of the [permutohedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutohedron), the [associahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associahedron), the [cyclohedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclohedron), ...

Comment: @Rahul:  Ah, I get it now!  Thanks for clearing that up.